# Stealing the redirect URL of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, salesforce, visualforce

Is it possibe to change the return URL of a button whose job is submitting a form to the server? The main deal here is that I don't have the script that controls the button, hence the word "stealing."

If you are curious about the use case, I have a Salesforce Visualforce page that has an embedded Flow in it. I want to jump out of the Flow when the user is half way through and a certain condition is met.

Comment: Is the embedded flow embedded by an `<iframe />` or otherwise? If it's via an `<iframe />`, is it on the same domain as the parent page or not? If it isn't, then this won't be possible.

Comment: No iframe. I know what you're talking about though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the button is not in an iFrame...

```
$('#some_button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff here then submit the form..
    $('#some_form').submit();
});
```

You could also use this method for `$('#some_form').submit()...`. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: Are you sure this is not a simple override? I still want the form to be submitted to the server, and I want the server to do its thing.. "Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered."

Comment: @user1936026 - You can still submit the form afterwards, it will just allow you to run your own code between when the button is clicked and the form is submitted. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let me rephrase this; I want the form submit to happen first, and then I want to redirect to a location of my choosing. But currently submitting the form redirects to somewhere that I don't want to go.